# Change Column value from 1 to 0

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column with 1 and 0 that I would like to change to the opposite.

```
|This   |Should be|
| 0     |1        |
| 1     |0        |
| 0     |1        |
| 1     |0        |
| 0     |1        |
```

I tried to do `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"0","1",""))`
But this changes all the values to 0, same thing if I do the Replace function :(

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,IF(A1:A*1=1, 0, 1)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,N(A1:A*1=0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=-A1+1`

[image]

I did it on Excel but it should work perfectly on Google Sheets.

Comment: Thank you @FoxFire But I'm not sure how to add this to the formula?

Comment: I thought you had 1 column with 1 and 0 and wanted to get the opposite. You can get the opposite in a new column and delete the old one.